# Is it possible to create a solution template with VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

i'm trying to find examples on the net about how to make a *solution* template. Everything leads to examples of *project* templates, which is not good enough for me. i'm after a solution template because I've got a number of projects I wish to put into the same solution and the make that a template.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like http://www.codeplex.com/treesurgeon, but using your custom solution scheme?

Comment: yep - something like that. That url shows an example of 3 projects in the solution being created.

Answer (score 1):

The [Guidance Automation Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/aa718948.aspx) can be used to create solution templates. For instance, the [Service Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/servicefactory) is done that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your Project Template:

```
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.BusinessLogic" >.\Project.BusinessLogic\MyTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.DataAccess">.\Project.DataAccess\MyTemplate.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
```

This is you main template and then you need folder in the template that has there own templates.